# why is this site not full viewport width on smaller devices?

Tags: html, ios, css, viewport

https://high-speed-business-club.com/secure/business-dna-super-profit-secrets/

On a shrunken desktop browser window it behaves OK. However, on iOS devices, there is a gap to the right. From what I can tell it is associated with .wrapper and #wrapper-2 however I have put in a media query and still experience the same result.

[image: iPhone 6S display. Elements will not occupy 100% of screen width.]

Answer (score 0):

use this code in CSS

```
.main-content .column, .main-content .box {
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Below Code In Your Css

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {

.main-content .column .box, .control-group .controls select { width:100%;}

}